# Pass dropdown value from view to Mvc contoller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to pass the selected dropdown value from my view to controller. I've used Mvc Music Store's shopping cart functionalities.

**Problem** : First I was able to pass the "Size" in the parameters and store, but when I added the SetColor(), It doesn't work.

I'm a beginner, Is there any other way to do this ?

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult AddToCart(int id , string Size, string Color)
    {
        var addedAlbum = storeDB.Products.Single(prod => prod.ProductId == id);
        string size = Size;
        string color = Color;
        var cart = ShoppingCart.GetCart(this.HttpContext);
        cart.AddToCart(addedAlbum, size, color);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

**View**

```
<span class="row">

   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      var ProductId = @Model.ProductId;
      var productSize = null;
      var productColor = null;
      function SetSize() {
        productSize = $("#Size").val();
      }

      function SetColor() {
        productColor = $("#Color").val();
      }

      function AddToCart(){
        window.location  = "/ShoppingCart/AddToCart?id=" + ProductId + "&Size=" + productSize + "&Color=" + productColor;
      }

   </script>

    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Size)
    <select onchange="SetSize()" id="Size" required>
      <option>--Select Size--</option>
      @foreach (var size in Model.Size.Split(','))
      {
        <option value="@size">@size</option>
      }
    </select>

    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Colors)
    <select onchange="SetColor()" id="Color" required>
      <option>--Select Color--</option>
      @foreach (var color in Model.Colors.Split(','))
      {
       <option value="@color">@color</option>
      }
    </select>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-fefault" onclick="AddToCart()">  Add to cart</button>
```

Comment: why aren't you using @Html.DropDownList() helper and SelectListItem available in MVC. You can add the helper inside a form and it will work

Comment: @AwaisMahmood Yeah I wrote it like this now

@ Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Size, new SelectList(Model.Size.Split(new char[] { ',' }), new { @ onchange = "SetSize()", @ id = "Size" } ))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have vars in global scope, i guess that is somehow not getting updated while you call the `AddToCart()` function. First solution i would mention to call the functions before you redirect:

```
function AddToCart(){
    SetSize(); // call here to set size
    SetColor(); // call here to set color

    window.location  = "/ShoppingCart/AddToCart?id=" + ProductId + 
                       "&Size=" + productSize + "&Color=" + productColor;
}
```

You have to assign the values instead:

```
function AddToCart(){
    productSize = $("#Size").val();
    productColor = $("#Color").val();
    window.location  = "/ShoppingCart/AddToCart?id=" + ProductId + 
                       "&Size=" + productSize + "&Color=" + productColor;
}
```

---

As per your comment, what you can do is just pass `this` in the calling function for both size and color:

```
onchange="SetSize(this)"
onchange="SetColor(this)"
```

then in the function you can update to:

```
function SetSize(sizeElem) {
  productSize = sizeElem.value;
}

function SetColor(colorElem) {
  productColor = colorElem.value;
}
```

Comment: This is not a solution

Comment: _Is there any other way to do this ?_  @DilipN This is what i saw and BTW i don't work in .NET env.

Comment: @Jai I wrote it using Html Helpers. Like this.

@ Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Size, new SelectList(Model.Size.Split(new char[] { ',' }), new { @ onchange = "SetSize()", @ id = "Size" }))

@ Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Colors, new SelectList(Model.Colors.Split(new char[] { ',' }), new { @ onchange = "SetColor()", @ id = "Color" }))

I'm getting the Size but Color: undefined

Comment: @UmerWaqar you can pass `this` as an argument in the function and then you can use with `paramname.value`. Wait i will add this too.

Comment: Glad to help you @UmerWaqar. See you again on SO